# Simple URL Rewrite issue

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

OK, I'm not familiar with URL rewriting. This is my first excursion into it. For my first attempt, I'm trying to do something very simple, rewrite this URL '/Top/Sub/Details.aspx?Id=0' to this URL '/Top/Sub/' and I'm doing it with the Intelligencia URL Rewriter like this:
`<rewrite url="~/Top/Sub/Details.aspx?Id=0" to="~/Top/Sub/" processing="stop" />`

But nothing is happening. The URL is being passed on as-is. Am I missing anything obvious here?

Comment: Rewriting happens "behind the scenes" --i.e., it is invisible to the browser. I think you want a *redirect*.

Comment: It's still a form of redirect, is it not? :) You match the url, rewrite it and then redirect to the new URL. As I said, mine was a _simple_ example. I.e. I'm not attempting any RegEx yet.

Comment: A rewrite isn't a form of redirect. It tells the server to serve the rewritten page instead of the one specified in the URL. So it won't change what the user sees in the browser.